# Como associar um conjunto de palavras para um método "do_" da classe Cmd?

Tags: python

Estou usando o a classe `Cmd` do [modulo cmd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) do Python para criar um interpretador para um jogo em Text Adventure. No entanto, me surgiu um problema em relação as palavras que eu uso como métodos para que o interpretador execute.

Veja este exemplo de ilustração:

```
import cmd

class Comando(cmd.Cmd):
  prompt = ">"

  def do_olhar(self, valor):
    print('Olhar em volta')

  def do_ver(self, valor):
    print('Olhar em volta')

  def do_pegar(self, valor):
    print('Pegar algo')

  def do_pega(self, valor):
    print('Pegar algo')

  def do_obter(self, valor):
    print('Pegar algo')

c = Comando()
c.cmdloop()
```

Repare que algumas palavras são parecidas e tem as mesmas finalidades, tais como `obter`, `pegar`, `pega`, `olha`, `olhar` e `ver`.

Portanto, eu gostaria de saber se é possível criar um método que esteja associado à um conjunto de palavras e não uma só como é o caso acima i.e. `do_palavra()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode, também, utilizar o método `cmd.precmd`, que conforme documentação:

> **Cmd.precmd(line)**
>
> *Hook method executed just before the command line line is interpreted,
>   but after the input prompt is generated and issued. This method is a
>   stub in Cmd; it exists to be overridden by subclasses. The return
>   value is used as the command which will be executed by the onecmd()
>   method; the precmd() implementation may re-write the command or simply
>   return line unchanged.*

O método é executado sempre antes do comando final ser executado e o valor retornado será o novo comando. Neste caso, você pode analisar o valor de `line`, verificar se o comando informado é um sinônimo de outro e retorná-lo.

```
SINONIMOS = {
  'ver': 'olhar',
  'pega': 'pegar',
  'obter': 'pegar'
}

def precmd(self, line):
  command, arguments, line = self.parseline(line)
  command = self.SINONIMOS.get(command, command)
  return ' '.join([command, arguments])
```

Ficaria algo assim:

```
import cmd

class Comando(cmd.Cmd):
  prompt = ">"

  SINONIMOS = {
    'ver': 'olhar',
    'pega': 'pegar',
    'obter': 'pegar'
  }

  def precmd(self, line):
    command, arguments, line = self.parseline(line)
    command = self.SINONIMOS.get(command, command)
    return ' '.join([command, arguments])

  def do_olhar(self, valor):
    print('Olhar em volta')

  def do_pegar(self, valor):
    print('Pegar algo')

  def default(self, line):
    print('Não sei o que fazer ¯\_(ツ)_/¯')

c = Comando()
c.cmdloop()
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/OldfashionedInformalModularity)</sup>

Resultado:

```
> ver
Olhar em volta
> pega
Pegar algo
> obter
Pegar algo
> pegar
Pegar algo
```

Comment: Esse método é melhor, vou apagar minha resposta

Comment: @nosklo acho que você poderia deixar sua resposta, é bom ter alternativas :)